# Unable to create .Net 4.0 application pools in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have installed ASP.NET 4 using the Web Platform installer of a Windows 2008 SP2 Server with IIS7.

The MVC sites work fine, when I set a default (created at an install time) ASP.NET 4.0 application pool to it.

But when I want my site to have it's own application pool, I am unable to create a new pool with .Net Framework 4 support - only .Net 2.0.

Is it a correct behaviour of IIS7? Do ASP.NET 4 apps all have to be hosted in the same default ASP.NET 4.0 app pool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In command prompt type `cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` and run `aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`. That should help you.